# how can i add angled border or something like this website has?

Tags: html, css

In this site, they used an image for the big one before www.acaml.com text and then how did they manage to
do this angle each after those navs?
pls check the image 
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using a background image ([URL of the background image](https://www.acaml.com/wp-content/themes/acaml/images/menu_divider.gif)) for the separator, not a CSS border. You can see this easily opening the developers tools in your browser.

```
#menu-header li{
background-image:url(../images/menu_divider.gif);
background-position:right;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-align:left;
line-height:20px;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:0px 45px 0px 8px;
margin-top:-4px;
}
```

Notice the 45px padding right to make space for the separator in the background

Answer (score 1):

They have used a gif as an image. You can use your web browser's developer tools (f12 or right click and then "inspect").

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tdhv.png)

You can also achieve that using css's pro`enter code here`perty transform:rotate(), [example here](https://codepen.io/Moshe_Mantsur/pen/mdVVVNb).